# Code returns all the items in Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, asp.net-mvc

In here i want to get allRefItems but it should be checked & NOT disabled.But in here always get 
all the Id's

```
var allRefItems = [];
$('table#reftable > tbody > tr').each(function () {
    if ($(this).find('td:eq(0) input', this).is(':checked')) {
        if ($(this).find('td:eq(0) input', this).not(':disabled')) {
            itId = $(this).find('td:eq(0) input', this).attr('id'); 
            allRefItems.push(itId);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Please add the markup, so we can easily reproduce.

Comment: You need `if ($(this).find('td:eq(0) input').is(':not(:disabled)')) {` or better, just select the elements you want using `$("input[type='checkbox']:checked:not(:disabled)")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get all checkboxes in table i think you could do it easier:

```
var allRefItems = [];
$('table#reftable > tbody input[type="checkbox"]') //get all checboxes
   .filter(function() { // filter them only checked and not disabled
      return !this.disabled && this.checked;
   }).each(function () { //getting your ids
      itId = $(this).attr('id'); 
      allRefItems.push(itId);
});
```

Here is an [jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/a647yxrb/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

```
var allRefItems = $('table#reftable > tbody > tr input[type="checkbox"]:checked:not(:disabled)').map(function() {
  return this.id;
}).get();
```